# sql sum and group by giving more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this query to get single total value:

```
SELECT SUM(`contact_awards`.`amount`) AS amount
FROM (`contact_awards`)
WHERE
    `contact_awards`.`gift_award_id` IN (1) 
AND `created` BETWEEN '2013-05-05' AND '2014-04-01'
GROUP
    BY `contact_awards`.`amount`
```

However when run, it products two rows containing `amount` field:

```
500
1000
```

Why doesn't it run single row with sum `1500` ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the `GROUP BY` clause,

```
SELECT SUM(contact_awards.amount) AS amount
FROM   contact_awards
WHERE  contact_awards.gift_award_id IN (1) 
       AND created BETWEEN '2013-05-05' AND '2014-04-01'
```

the reason why you are getting two records is because there are two different values of `contact_awards.amount` being grouped.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `group by`, the results are going to be separated by your grouping clause. IF you want a single row summed up, simply remove the `group by` at the end of your query.